# Creating a simple volume in Windows 7 Disk Management - Warning about not being able to boot if I do so

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, dynamic-disk

I am trying to create a partition on my Laptop through **Windows Disk Management** so I can install Ubuntu on a new partition using Wubi. However, I get a warning that says something like "If you make this a Dynamic Disk, you wont be able to boot installed OS'es from this disk" (Sorry, original is in Danish).

I am afraid to continue. Could it be that I get this warning because I already have 4 partitions? (Due to HP making them, grr).

Comment: Are you trying to create a partition yourself. Or are you talking about something that pops up during the install process. I don't remember ever having to do anything manually using the WUBI installer.

Comment: trying to create it myself in Disk Management (as stated in the title :) )

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I saw that right after I commented, and answered based on your well stated title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like at one time WUBI was trickier on Windows 7 however the [latest on the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) seems to indicate that it works normally now. In other words just use the WUBI installer and let it take care of everything. You shouldn't have to do anything with disk management.  Typically for new users I work with, we will start with a persistent USB boot for a day or two to build interest, maybe a WUBI install for a week or two to see if they grow to love it, then a full dual boot (though many just leave Windows behind). I just mention these because all options are available depending on the level of commitment.
Other useful info may be found at
[WUBI guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)
[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu%29)

Comment: So no need for partitioning?

Comment: If someone tells me this is wrong and or dangerous I will delete it but in my experience this has always been the advantage of WUBI. It is created within a file on an existing file system. It has a few downfalls for long term use but I have installed and uninstalled several with no ill effect.

Comment: Cheers, accepting this! :)

Comment: +1, installing to an existing partition is *exactly* the point of Wubi.

Comment: So I just installed it on my HP Pavillion DV7, and ehmm.. Wireless is not working. :(

Comment: That isn't unusual, wireless is one thing that half the time (almost all Broadcom ) can need a driver.  That is a different question and if you just start with Google using Ubuntu and Wireless you will get a bunch of hits. For me just going to the "Additional Drivers" app and letting it find and install them will work about 90% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

(I *just* [answered a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/339063/windows-7-no-primary-partition-is-this-wrong)...)

You're right about the four partition limit in legacy MBR.

Currently you are trying to create a fifth partition without having an 'extended' partition to put it into, and Windows cannot automatically convert existing partitions into logical ones, so it is offering to convert the entire disk into Microsoft's [Logical Disk Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) partitioning scheme ("Dynamic disks").

Unfortunately, neither the GRUB bootloader nor grub4dos (used by Wubi) are able to boot from a 'dynamic disk'. You should reject the conversion offer, delete the fourth primary partition and create an 'extended' one in place of it. (The HP junk is okay to delete.)

Comment: You can also use third party software like Paragon Partition Manager that can convert primary partitions to extended ones. If your BIOS supports UEFI, you should also be able to convert the partition table scheme to GPT which will remove all restrictions. (Only do this if you're 100% sure your motherboard can boot from GPT.)

Comment: @Grawity - I dont supposed the HP_TOOLS partition are necesarry then - however if I need to reinstall Windows, wont I need them? Like, HP has this wireless connection manager that is controlled by a touch element on my laptop.

Comment: @Jeff: You can backup the tools, and re-create the partition later.